# I try the hide banner and categories component whlle routes are AuthRoute and ProductRoute

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<React.Fragment>
  <div style={{"height": "100vh",
  }}>
   <Navbar/>
    <Switch>

      <Route path={"/"} component={DefaultRoutes} />
      <Route path="/auth/login" component={AuthRoutes} />
      <Route path={"/product/:id"} component={ProductRoutes} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

Default route has main path and have banner and categories component but when ı try go anoher route nothing change and my component not render in screen anybody know whats going on

Comment: which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: sory ı forgat it thats V5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `Switch` component, path order and specificity matters.

[Switch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

> Renders the ***first*** (*emphasis mine*) child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
> location.

Order the routes in decreasing order by path specificity, i.e. `"/path1/path2"` is more specific than `"/path1"` is more specific than `"/"`. For the specific code in your snippet you can just move the home `"/"` path to be last in the `Switch` so the other more specific paths can possibly be matched first.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/auth/login" component={AuthRoutes} />
  <Route path={"/product/:id"} component={ProductRoutes} />
  <Route path={"/"} component={DefaultRoutes} />
</Switch>
```